# JQuery Commands Breaking Each Other

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have this code to produce a certain form based on selection.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dealerform').hide();
    $('#customerform').hide();
    $('#select').change(function(){
        $('#dealerform,#customerform').hide();
        $($(this).find('option:selected').attr('value')).show();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='emailquest']").change(function(){
    if (this.value != "1") { // <----I would probably change this to look for this.checked
        $("input[name='email']").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $("input[name='email']").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    });
});
```

Well now I have added some code to try to add a datepicker to it as well with this code and now it breaks my previous code and just serves up the whole thing at once and the datepicker doesnt' work.  Does someone know what im doing wrong here and have a possible datepicker solution?

```
$(function(){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Checked your console for errors?

Comment: Try putting everything in $(function(){});    (including the document.ready stuff)

Comment: You've essentially got 3 document ready wrappers...you only need one

Comment: Can you post your HTML and create a jsFiddle?

Comment: FYI, `$(function(){` is the exact same as `$(document).ready(function(){`, and is only needed when calling jQuery/JS in the `<head>` of your page, and is only needed once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary to wrap each code bock in a new $(document.ready().

This:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#dealerform').hide();
    $('#customerform').hide();
    $('#select').change(function(){
        $('#dealerform,#customerform').hide();
        $($(this).find('option:selected').attr('value')).show();
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='emailquest']").change(function(){
    if (this.value != "1") { // <----I would probably change this to look for this.checked
        $("input[name='email']").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $("input[name='email']").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    });
});                     
$(function(){
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Can be written like this:

```
$(function() {
    //  your first block of code
    $('#dealerform').hide();
    $('#customerform').hide();
    $('#select').change(function(){
        $('#dealerform,#customerform').hide();
        $($(this).find('option:selected').attr('value')).show();
    });

    // your second block of code
    $("input[name='emailquest']").change(function(){
        if (this.value != "1") { // <----I would probably change this to look for this.checked
            $("input[name='email']").prop("disabled", true);
        }
        else {
            $("input[name='email']").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    });

    // that last piece
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
})
```

---

Remember, that if you are using both jQuery and jQueryUI (datepicker is from jQueryUI), then you must reference both libraries, something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                //  your first block of code
                $('#dealerform').hide();
                $('#customerform').hide();
                $('#select').change(function(){
                    $('#dealerform,#customerform').hide();
                    $($(this).find('option:selected').attr('value')).show();
                });

                // your second block of code
                $("input[name='emailquest']").change(function(){
                    if (this.value != "1") { // <----I would probably change this to look for this.checked
                        $("input[name='email']").prop("disabled", true);
                    }
                    else {
                        $("input[name='email']").prop("disabled", false);
                    }
                });

                // that last piece
                $("#datepicker").datepicker();
            })
        </script>
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();

    $('#dealerform').hide();
    $('#customerform').hide();
    $('#select').change(function(){
        $('#dealerform,#customerform').hide();
        $($(this).find('option:selected').attr('value')).show();
    });

    $("input[name='emailquest']").change(function(){
    if (this.value != "1") { // <----I would probably change this to look for this.checked
        $("input[name='email']").prop("disabled", true);
    } else {
        $("input[name='email']").prop("disabled", false);
    }
    });
});
```